# Re_expanding the SD-Card after raspberry pi start-up

Tags: raspbian, noobs

How do I expand the SD card on the Raspberry Pi after I have started using the Pi without the initial partition expansion required at strat up, using NOOBS (raspbian)?

Comment: Using `raspi-config` isn't limited to the first boot of Raspbian.  You should still be able to call `sudo raspi-config` and tell it to expand.  It might be different because of the NOOBS bit, though, which is why this is a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Raspbian, the `raspi-config` tool should come preinstalled.

Simply open a terminal and call `sudo raspi-config`. You are then presented with a menu that allows you to expand the SD card.

Answer (score 1):

Open the command line and type `sudo raspi-config`.

A menu will appear. Use your keyboard to navigate to option one and press enter. However, if you a using NOOBS, the SD Card is generally expanded anyway.

Comment: I am using NOOBS and it does say that it expanded automatically but the card is now only a total space of 983MB instead of the 16 GB

Comment: Does it say that when you plug it in to a computer running Windows, or the Pi itself? If it says that on Windows, it is because the SD card will have been formatted in the correct way for the Pi. Only the 983MB will have been FAT32, which Windows reads.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.